# How to make a testable wrapper around Threading.Timer and replace it when unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, timer, moq, wrapper

I am struggling more than one day already with testing of my `System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback callback, object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period);` overload.

Basing on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367701/12603542) I created my **ThreadingTimer**, **FakeTimer**, that implements **ITimer**:

```
public interface ITimer
    {
        bool Change(int dueTime, int period);
        bool IsDisposed { get; }

        void Dispose();
    }


public class ThreadingTimer : ITimer, IDisposable
    {
        private Timer _timer;

        public ThreadingTimer(TimerCallback callback, object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(callback, state, dueTime, period);
        }

        public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            IsDisposed = true;
            Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        public bool Change(int dueTime, int period)
        {
            _timer.Change(dueTime, period);

            return true;
        }
    }

public class FakeTimer : ITimer
    {
        private object state;

        public FakeTimer(TimerCallback callback, object state)
        {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

        public bool Change(int dueTime, int period)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            IsDisposed = true;
            Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

In my service class I want to make usage of my **ThreadingTimer**:

```
public ITimer Timer { get; set; }
private void StartUpdates()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Timer = new ThreadingTimer(StartUpdatingVessels, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

            }, Token);
        }
```

BUT when it comes to unit testing, I have no idea and understanding how to make usage and advantage of implementing of **ITimer** in my **FakeTimer**. Because if in my test will be called method `StartUpdates()`, new instance of **ThreadingTimer** will be created, even if already **Timer** prop has assigned **FakeTimer**:

```
[Fact]
        public void SetUpdatingStarted_CalledWhenUpdatingAlreadyStarted_DisposesTimer()
        {
            _timedUpdateControl.Timer = new FakeTimer(CallbackTestMethod, null);
            bool intendedToStartUpdates = false;

            _timedUpdateControl.StartOrStopUpdates(intendedToStartUpdates); //that methid calls private method StartUpdates() and creates instance for ITimer

            //assert something
        }
```

How hould I mock it there? (I am using **Moq** framework in test project).

Comment: You should make use of dependency injection or a factory of some sort

Comment: @Michael I was considering this. Lets say, I will create new mock of ITimer, how to use it in my test method?

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use Dependency Injection:

```
public interface ITimer
{
    event Action Elapsed;
    void StartTimer(int dueTime, int period);
    bool IsDisposed { get; }

    void Dispose();
}

public class TimedUpdateControl
{
    private ITimer timer;

    public TimedUpdateControl(ITimer timer)
    {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.timer.Elapsed += () => { // do something }
    }

    private void StartUpdates()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            timer.StartTimer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        }, Token);
    }
}
```

The test:

```
[Fact]
public void SetUpdatingStarted_CalledWhenUpdatingAlreadyStarted_DisposesTimer()
{
    var timedUpdateControl = new TimedUpdateControl(new FakeTimer());
    bool intendedToStartUpdates = false;

    timedUpdateControl.StartOrStopUpdates(intendedToStartUpdates); 

    //assert something
}
```

Comment: At the beginning I was worrying that, that your solution does not use `TimerCallback` in constructor, but I realized, that it fixes many problems related with triggering callback by constructor in my solution. I will try to implement your way and I will come back soon... Thank you.

Comment: Ok, now I think that I get everyting right and understand what I did wrong. I used similar to your approach, with **Moq**, but anyway, I can accept your answer.